# Tab spaces lost after POST

Tags: php, windows, ubuntu

I am using ace editor plugin on my web application written in PHP. This has probably nothing to do with ace editor. Rather, it's probably have to do with the difference encoding methods between the OSs.

Tab indentations and line breaks are lost after form is submitted via POST in production (Ubuntu). However, it works on my local windows dev machine.

I am able to "encode" line breaks by replacing "\r\n" and "\n" with '\n'. However, I cannot find a way to encode tab keys.

Comment: A tab key is the control character **\t**.

Comment: @thedom I have attempted to str_replace( array("\r\t", "\t"), '\t', $var ); but it doesn't work.

Comment: How do you submit the code? Are you manipulating it? What do you want to do with your manipulation (``str_replace()``)?

Comment: I am submitting via html form POST method. Simply doing a php echo shows that the tab spaces are already lost. I am trying to save the submitted code to database.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code at pastebin.com or so? There must be something removing the formatting.

Comment: I will post the code when I get access to it later (only a few lines). The problem only occurs when I push it to my Ubuntu server. Works perfectly on my Windows dev machine. Same thing happens to line breaks. So I suspect it has got something to do with how the OS encodes the characters.